# QFrame : create mousePressEvent

Tags: qt, events, qt5, qt-designer

actually i'm trying to get a mousePressEvent for a QFrame in QT 5 (VS2010 with Qt-Addin). Saw so many suggestons here and on other forums, but newer got it to work, or i didnt understood the princip. Also looked at the [scribble](http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/4.5/widgets-scribble.html) example, with no luck

How can i get the mousePressEvent for a QFrame? Do i have to create a class that is inheriting from a QFrame and then initialize this frame on my own in the main()-function? isnt there a solution that i can bind it to the Qt-Designer?

tried multiple things, mostly saw something like this:

```
protected:
void TestQtFormsApplication::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *qevent)
{
    if (qevent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->close();
    }
};
```

with this i ever got the error C2027: use of undefined type 'QMouseEvent'

Comment: Did you forget nesessary includes?

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QFrame>

Comment: the C2027 error is now fixed, forgot to include all necessary files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `QFrame` and reimplement `mousePressEvent(..)` much like you have in your example.  Remember to `accept()` the event to stop it propagating to the parent widget.  Your error is because `QMouseEvent` is only forward declared in the `QWidget` header file, just include it yourself.

If you want to use your subclass in Qt Designer, just use a `QFrame` and the 'Promote' it to your subclass ([docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets)).

Comment: i've promoted now a QFrame to a CustomFrame. CustomFrame is now subclass of QFrame, but it now throws me errors that it couldnt find any matching constructors, so i think the were not interhited from QFrame, how to solve this? CustomFrame.h looks like this and the old implementation from above is in the .cpp file

class DragDropFrame : public QFrame
{
protected:
 void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *qevent);
};

Comment: @Postback Err... That code does not even have a constructor in it!  You will need one that takes a `QWidget*` so the parent can be specified.

Comment: ohh, forgot that completly. thx has solved the problem and now everything works like it should